# Adding a number to the end of a string?

Tags: jquery

I have a variable that stores a link id.

HTML

```
<a href="#tab-1">PREFORMANCE REELS</a>
```

jQuery

```
var tab = $(this).attr("href");
```

I have another variable that does the same thing but the link is an increment of 5.

HTML

```
<a href="#tab-6">PREFORMANCE REELS</a>
```

How do I write the variable to add 5 to the end of it? So #tab-1 becomes #tab-6?

Comment: Do you want to increment the *existing* element's href or add a *new* element with the incremented href?

Comment: I want to increment the existing one by 1 and store it in the variable called tab because the next line of code is $(".tab-content").not(tab).css("display", "none");

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use this function

```
function  addnum(tab){
   var getnum = parseInt((tab.split('-'))[1]);
   var add5 = ((tab.split('-'))[0]) + '-'+ (getnum + 5) ;
   return add5;
}
```

use it like that

```
var tab = $(this).attr("href");
alert(addnum(tab));
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/yo9qyujw/1/)

Answer (score -1):

You could replace "#tab-" by nothing "" then you have the number and just add 5 to it

I hope It helps you

Regards